# Problem with hover over images in slimbox.js

Tags: javascript, slimbox

I am developing a site in Joomla and have used an extension called ‘image browser’ to display a gallery. The image browser extension is made from slimbox.js.

I have inserted PayPal buttons into the caption so they display when you click the image, but I am trying to break the tooltips that pop up showing the HTML code when you hover over an image.

It is too late to switch to another gallery, and I have viewed a few different posts on this subject but none of them uses slimbox.js, they all use light box, and that hasn't helped me.

The website is http://www.whiteriverphotography.net

Comment: PNG images containing photographs? :-S You mean the title attributes containing markup? E.g. on [this page](http://www.whiteriverphotography.net/index.php?option=com_imagebrowser&view=gallery&Itemid=84) the title attributes of the thumbnails are filled with markup. Where is the code that injected markup into those attributes?

Comment: Actually, this is *not* a client-side problem, as the markup is already injected at the server-side, as ‘View source’ reveals.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly work around would be

```
var bodyNodes = document.getElementById("body").childNodes,
    i = bodyNodes.length;

while (i--) {
    if (bodyNodes[i].className == "thumbnail")
        bodyNodes[i].firstChild.title = "";
}
```

which removes all `title` attributes of the `a` elements within `.thumbnail` divs.

Comment: Couyld i just insert this anywhere into the slimbox.js? or is there a specific spot to place it. (completely new to js)

Comment: @mccollins: You should put this at a place where `#body` has entirely been loaded *or* in the onload handler.

Comment: Still working on figuring out just where to place it, decided to actually start learning script.  Ive placed it in numerous parts of my code, and it hasnt worked yet.

Comment: @mccollins: You can place it before the `</body>` end tag.